# Testing an app on device; Installing Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode

- I am trying to test my app on a device but am unable to do it as says that

"The version of iOS on “iPhone” does not match any of the versions of iOS supported for development with this installation of the iOS SDK. Please restore the device to a version of the OS listed below, or update to the latest version of the iOS SDK; which is available here.

OS Installed on iPhone
5.1 (9B179)

Xcode Supported iOS Versions
Latest
5.0 (9A334)
4.3
4.2"

- Now I know that i have the latest iOS deployed in the iPhone. But my installed Xcode's version is "4.2.1" whereas in App Store the latest version is "4.3.2". Also, in App Store it shows up as "Installed" which means that I need to run the "Install Xcode" app from my applications.

  - Now, when I run "Install Xcode", it fails saying that there was an error encountered. In install.log file, the message logged is as below

> "Failed install preflight: Error Domain=PKInstallErrorDomain Code=102
>   "The package “DeveloperTools.pkg” is untrusted."
>   UserInfo=0x7fc3c9e602a0 {NSLocalizedDescription=The package
>   “DeveloperTools.pkg” is untrusted.,
>   NSURL=../Packages/DeveloperTools.pkg --
>   file://localhost/Applications/Install%20Xcode.app/Contents/Resources/Xcode.mpkg/,
>   PKInstallPackageIdentifier=com.apple.pkg.DeveloperToolsLeo,
>   NSUnderlyingError=0x7fc3cbdc42d0 "The operation couldn’t be completed.
>   CSSMERR_TP_CERT_EXPIRED"}"

Now, how to fix it. I have ensured that there is no other software update pending in the system which may have potentially caused any issues in Xcode installation.

PS - I am using Lion, current Xcode version is Version 4.2.1 and the issue occurs on all iOS devices.

Comment: If you have downloaded the xcode from the Mac App Store, then check for update of it. You dont have to run the "install xcode" from your applications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a problem with updating from 4.2 in the app store as noted here:  https://developer.apple.com/xcode/ - which is why the app store is not letting you update eventhough you do not have the latest version.

It sounds from your question as if you are trying to reinstall using the installer you already have.  If you have not done so already you should log into the apple dev center and download the installer from there (from full tools download list - main screen just links to app store).  once on 4.3 updating from app store for future updates should work fine.

Comment: where the problem is noted in the link provided?

Comment: in the "note" under the block for downloading 4.3 - middle of the page it says: "The update from Xcode 4.2 will not show up in the Mac App Store "Updates" tab. Updates will work as normal for Xcode 4.3 and later."   - This is a known problem that happened right after xcode first went into the app store.

Comment: For future reference, here is the link for direct downloads - https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action